# Instance variable in rails - apart from views where can we use it and for how long is it available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a instance variable in rails project, which gets its value from a url parameter like `example.com/value`. This variable is created in `new` action, now can it also be used in `create` action, of the same model.

The `value` is a `id` of another model altogether and both the models are associated, I need to create the instance variable in former model.

I need to know, for how long the instance variable is available, and can be use the instance variable of one model in another model.

**Clarification with real example**

Supposingly there are two models, one is `User` model and other is `Referral` model. The root is `root :to => 'users#new`. Now the user will coming here via `example.com/value`, where `value` is the `id` for `Referral` model. Now using this `value` I have to increment two fields: One is `visits`, which shows how many visits did that particular url bring. Other is `signup`, which will increment if there is a signup using that `value`.

I have passed this `value` via routes in `users#new`, which I use to increment the `visits` column of `Referral` model. Now if the users signup, the `users#create` would be executed, and I want to be able to use the `value` in the create action as well, to increment the `signup` column in `Referral` model.

As of now, I understand that the instance variable I created in `new` action to store the `value` cannot be used in `create` action. Now how can I achieve this.

Comment: Could you show us an example of how this variable is being used? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: I have added a more real example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general instance variables only last as long as the user's HTTP request, so they can not be created in one action and used in another.

You could try storing the variable in the session, a hidden input field on the HTML form generated by the `new` action, or in the urls of links generated by the `new` action.

I don't know exactly what you are doing, but from the names of your two actions it sounds like there is probably an HTML form involved, so I think the best thing is to use a hidden input, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="model_id" value="<%= @model_id %>" />
```

Comment: I agree, if you're just trying to pass the data... then post it through. Using hidden inputs like above is a good way to accomplish this.

Comment: Hidden field can only be used, when the model has that column model_id, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables only last for that call and in the class they are defined, with the exception of the views.  If you have a controller with two methods where one method is your route and another is used internally, then it will be available to both, it is also available to your views.

e.g.

test_controller.rb

```
def index
  something_else
  p @variable #outputs "foo" in the terminal
end

def something_else
  @variable = "foo"
end
```

However it would not be available between create and new as these would be called in different requests.

Comment: I now understand that instance variable are destroyed in the next request. I have also clarified the question, can you please clear my doubt.